# Listview Id Changes

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, listadapter

I have read through the forums and I can't seem to figure out how to get the position of the selected item to match my array list items since the listview is searchable.  It works great until I search then my items do not match up.  Can someone provide an exact example?

```
private void displayListView() {
        ArrayList<Country> countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();

        //countryList.clear();


        // int j=1;
        for (int i = 0; i < categoriesList.size(); i++) {

            //list.add(new ItemData(categoriesList.get(i).getName(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));

            //Array list of countries

            Country country = new Country(workordertypeId.get(i),ActualCity.get(i),ClientName.get(i),
                    ProjectNotes.get(i), ProjectStart.get(i),ProjectFieldNotes.get(i),ProjectStatus.get(i));
            countryList.add(country);


            ///////list.add(new StringWithTag(categoriesList.get(i).getName(),categoriesList2.get(i).getName()));
            //list.add(new ItemData("testthis",R.drawable.logolong4));

        }






        //create an ArrayAdaptar from the String Array
        dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this,
                R.layout.country_info, countryList);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        //enables filtering for the contents of the given ListView
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        //listView.has

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
                setwoindex(position);
                //setwoindex (parent.getSelectedItemPosition());
                //listView.getItemId(position)
                Country country = (Country) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                //country.getCode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                //country.getRegion(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                String haspdf = getIntent().getExtras().getString("haspdf", "defaultKey");

                if (haspdf.equals("1")) {
                    //counter++;
                    btnAddNewCategory.setText("Save PDF");
                    btnAddNewCategory.setEnabled(true);
                } else if (haspdf.equals("0")) {
                    btnAddNewCategory.setEnabled(false);
                }
                if (haspdf.equals("3")) {
                    //counter++;
                    btnAddNewCategory.setText("Save Image");
                    btnAddNewCategory.setEnabled(true);
                } else if (haspdf.equals("0")) {
                    btnAddNewCategory.setEnabled(false);
                }

                //updateGUI();
                //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "test",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //spinnerFood.setTag(pos);
                if (getwoindex() != null) {
                   // punchin.setEnabled(true);
                    Viewattachments.setEnabled(true);

                    //punchin.setEnabled(true);
                    // punchout.setEnabled(true);
                    //btnAddNewCategory.setEnabled(true);


                    int index = getwoindex();


                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"WorkOrderNumber Toasting="+ workordertypeId.get(index).toString() +" "+ClientName.get(index).toString()+" "+ActualCity.get(index).toString()+" "+ClientPhone.get(index).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    FullAddress.setText(WoClientName.get(index).toString() + "\n" + WoClientStreet.get(index).toString() + "\n" + ActualCity.get(index).toString() + " " + WoClientState.get(index).toString() + " " + WoClientZip.get(index).toString());
                    ActualPhone.setText(WoClientPhone.get(index).toString());
                    String IdUser = getIntent().getStringExtra("IdUser");
                    String usernameforlogin = getIntent().getStringExtra("usernameforlogin");

                    mrcastrovinci();
                }

            }


        });

        EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
        myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

    }

    private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Country> {

        private ArrayList<Country> originalList;
        private ArrayList<Country> countryList;
        private CountryFilter filter;

        public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                               ArrayList<Country> countryList) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, countryList);
            this.countryList = new ArrayList<Country>();
            this.countryList.addAll(countryList);
            this.originalList = new ArrayList<Country>();
            this.originalList.addAll(countryList);
        }


        @Override
        public boolean hasStableIds() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public android.widget.Filter getFilter() {
            if (filter == null){
                filter  = new CountryFilter();
            }
            return filter;
        }


        private class ViewHolder {
            TextView code;
            TextView name;
            TextView continent;
            TextView region;
            TextView Dated;
            TextView ProjectFieldNotes;
            TextView ProjectStatus;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder = null;
            Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));
            if (convertView == null) {

                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.country_info, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
                holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.continent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.continent);
                holder.region = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.region);
                holder.Dated = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dated);
                holder.ProjectFieldNotes = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ProjectFieldNotes);
                holder.ProjectStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ProjectStatus);




                convertView.setTag(holder);

            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Country country = countryList.get(position);
            holder.code.setText(country.getCode());
            holder.name.setText(country.getName());
            holder.continent.setText(country.getContinent());
            holder.region.setText(country.getRegion());
            holder.Dated.setText(country.getDated());
            holder.ProjectFieldNotes.setText(country.getProjectFieldNotes());
            holder.ProjectStatus.setText(country.getProjectStatus());

            return convertView;

        }

        private class CountryFilter extends android.widget.Filter
        {

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint != null && constraint.toString().length() > 0)
                {
                    ArrayList<Country> filteredItems = new ArrayList<Country>();

                    for(int i = 0, l = originalList.size(); i < l; i++)
                    {
                        Country country = originalList.get(i);
                        if(country.toString().toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                            filteredItems.add(country);
                    }
                    result.count = filteredItems.size();
                        result.values = filteredItems;
            }
            else
            {
                synchronized(this)
                {
                    result.values = originalList;
                    result.count = originalList.size();
                }
            }
            return result;
            //setwoindex(ListView1.getSelectedItemPosition());

            }






            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                                          FilterResults results) {

                countryList = (ArrayList<Country>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                clear();
                for(int i = 0, l = countryList.size(); i < l; i++)
                    add(countryList.get(i));
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: Consider adding a tag for android to get better answers

Comment: Any have any idea?  Thanks

Comment: Seems to me that you don't keep track of what you show in publish results.

Comment: It's some time cause due to larger size of listview items row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be acceptable to extend the Country object to contain an id/index?

If yes, that would be stored all the way and you could retrieve it back in the onItemClick for you ListView.

If not, you could build a wrapper around the Country object and either feed that to the adapter or have the adapter construct a list of wrappers.

```
public class MyWrapper {
    public Country mCountry;
    public int mOriginalIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes I actually just extended my country list and included all my items there.   I will add an index Id also.